# Should I use inline JS validation for optimization of page?

Tags: javascript, html

My company is using different modules / screens for different purposes. One of the screen is having a long form for data verification. In that form, the programmers are using multiple JS Alerts (1-2 alerts for email format, 2-3 alerts for mobile number format etc.)

Now, for optimizing the screen, I want to suggest them to use Inline JS Validation instead of using JS Alerts.

Please suggest, which one is better for optimization of the page.

Comment: html5 validation is better than both

Comment: This is off topic for SO. @dandavis—if HTML5 validation to worked perfectly on every browser that I have to deal with, great. But it doesn't come close.

Comment: @RobG: it works on most, and you can polyfill the rest. my main  point is to use the custom validation message as a place to give feedback to the user instead of using alert(). it looks better (next to the invalid input visually) and plays better with AT than many jq-based validations and alert, and it has a chance of working without JS. you should always do html5 attribs, and expand on that declarative markup with JS when needed.

Answer (score 0):

As an enduser I would prefer Inline feedback/error messages.

- Users seeing the context of that error
- Alerts makes more sense, when you get an error in a server response
- Inline errors, are more common these days, and it's good when an application follows the (unofficial) industry standards

All of these points are related to UI/UX. I hope this is what you mean with "page optimization"